# Placing an item beneath another inside a flexbox based display

Tags: html, css

I have a flexbox based item that displays an image and grows the second div based on the content inside. However, i would like to place some link beneath the heading text and a line break isn't working and i would like a solution that isn't a line break. The page looks like this https://jsfiddle.net/mrah1psg/

and this is the code

```css
#main {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#main div {
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.mt{
  margin-top:0px;
}
.grow-this{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 7 !important;
}
```

```html
    
<h1>FlexBox</h1>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558543936-49604317cd3b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" width="200px" height="200px" /></div>
<div class="grow-this" style="background-color:lightblue;">
  <h3 class="mt">Such a great title here that is flexible and sets width</h3>
  <a href="">An Address</a></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">Very Good</div>
</div>
```

I would like this link `<a href="">An Address</a>` to be displayed just beneath the title. How can i display the link beneath the title?

Comment: flex-direction:column? to .grow-this?

Comment: @TemaniAfif wow that works. How about if i want to auto grow the columns when i add a new item?

Comment: remove that fixed height your are setting or be more specific and target only the needed div, not all of them